# PyMongo search and sorting non-repeating values (KeyError: 'weight')

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I have data like this :

```
_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"colla"
weight:"2"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946

_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"pepsi"
weight:"3"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946

_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"colla"
weight:"3"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946
```

From that i want to find all non-repeating elements with `"name": "colla", 'status': '+'` and equate to random variable.

Example: from data above get all "weights" (2,3) and equate. (some_random1 = 2, some_random2 = 3)

How I tried:  `list(db.some_db.find({}, {"name": "cola","status":'+'})).sort(key=itemgetter('weight'), reverse=True)`, but I'm getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'weight'
```

Thx for your help

Comment: I think you are using find in wrong way. `db.some_db.find({"name": "cola","status":'+'})` should give you the right result.

Comment: I was trying. Getting "None" then.

Comment: What do you get for these: `print db.some_db.find({}).count()` , `print db.some_db.find({"name": "cola"}).count()` & `print db.some_db.find({"status":'+'}).count()` I think one of your query parameter is not working.

Comment: output: 5, 5, 5

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your query.

```
documents = db.some_db.find({'name': 'colla', 'status': '+'})
documents.sort(key=lambda doc: doc.get('weight', None), reverse=True)
```

Using `itemgetter`, you have to be *really* certain all documents have a weight field. Using a lambda here is a non-strict way of sorting by weight. 
The query result can be restricted to finding documents that have the weight field.

```
documents = db.some_db.find({
                'name': 'colla', 'status': '+', 'weight': {'$exists': True},
            })
```

Lastly, the query result can be restricted to finding documents that have weight to be 2 or 3.

```
documents = db.some_db.find({
                'name': 'colla', 'status': '+', 'weight': {'$in': [2, 3]},
            })
```